# Why can I not connect with wvdial? (Reliance Netconnect + issue with Kubuntu)

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, wvdial

The WVDIAL tutorial is very useful for me, unfortunately I am still not able to connect via wvdial but the other Hybrid connection method was simply Out of the Box.

I am getting below error while running `wvdial`

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial  
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done wvdial is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
sudo wvdial --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61  
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory  
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory  
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

I have run `sudo apt-get update` first and then run `sudo apt-get install wvdial` but still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution, I think this should be share with everuone hence posting....

I found a command : `kdesudo wvdial` while hunting on Google. Below is the Terminal output.

```
mahesh@Mahesh-System-Kubuntu:~$ kdesudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT#777
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Wed Feb  6 21:50:55 2013
--> Pid of pppd: 5481
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> local  IP address 115.241.164.245
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> remote IP address 220.224.141.129
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> primary   DNS address 220.226.100.40
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> secondary DNS address 220.226.6.104
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> Connect time 0.0 minutes.
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> local  IP address 115.241.164.245
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> remote IP address 220.224.141.129
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> primary   DNS address 220.226.100.40
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
--> secondary DNS address 220.226.6.104
--> pppd: À[1b]@[08][18]@[08]
```

Thank you all for your kind support!